# Iterating over HashMap then writing integers into file

Tags: java, hashmap, bufferedwriter, writetofile

I have been trying for quite some time to Iterate over a HashMap and then write the keys from the HashMap into a file.

This is what I have been doing

```
HashMap<String,Integer> myHashMap = new Hashmap<String,Integer>();

 myHashMap.put(aString,1)
 myHashMap.put(bString,2)
 myHashMap.put(cString,3)
//..

private void doStuff(){
try {
        // Create new file
        String path = "myCreatedTxt.txt";
        File file = new File(path);

        // If file doesn't exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> dic : myHashMap.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(dic.getKey() + "/" + dic.getValue());
            bw.write(dic.getKey()+"");
        }

        // Close connection
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException x) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

But when doStuff() is called, although a file named myCreatedTxT is created, it's empty.

I am expecting to get a result that would look something like:

`---inside myCreatedFile.txt---
1 11 4 2 5 6 7`

In an way I tried before I could only get a single key written on the file but that wasn't enough, as I need every key.

I would like to hear some advice or explanations

Thanks.

P.S of course, doStuff() is called somewhere in the program in a finally{} block.

Comment: `myHashMap.put(aString,i)` - you are putting values with the same key into the `Map`. You have confused key and value.

Comment: And what makes you think that `myHashMap` has more than one value?

Comment: I have surely made a mistake while creating this thread.
I am sure that myHashMap has more than one values since when I return the entrySet() i get someting like : 1 = aString , 2 = bString , 3 = dString.
I will edit my post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created `Writer` class for this example :

```
public class Writer {
    private Map<String, Integer> myHashMap;

    public Writer() {
        myHashMap = new HashMap<>();

        myHashMap.put("a", 1);
        myHashMap.put("b", 2);
        myHashMap.put("c", 3);
    }


    public void doStuff() {
        try {
            // Create new file
            final String path = "myCreatedTxt.txt";
            File file = new File(path);

            // If file doesn't exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);


            myHashMap.entrySet().forEach(x -> {
                try {
                    bw.write(x.getKey() + " ");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("error accord");
                }
            });

            // Close connection
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException x) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

And invoked it from my `main` class :

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
           Writer writer = new Writer();

           writer.doStuff();
        }
}
```

My output file looks exactly like that :

```
a b c
```

That should do the work

Comment: Thanks for your answer, indeed it works!
Can you explain what you are doing differently in the way your are iterating through the entrySet than I am ?

Comment: I don't get the:
 myHashMap.entrySet().forEach(x -> {
                try {
                    bw.write(x.getKey() + " ");
                }

Comment: I used Lambdas & streams that come with java 8, you can read more about it here : https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-applying-lambdas-to-java-collections/

Comment: if the answer helped you, I'll appreciate if you mark it as the right answer @JohnR.